# Objective-C crash issue: NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, xcode4

I am stuck in it for a long time, but can not find a solution. Here is my code:`

```
NSLog(@"[tempArray retainCount]: %d",[tempArray retainCount]);    
tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[allRemainingProductsDictionary objectForKey:[[allRemainingProductsDictionary allKeys]objectAtIndex:counter]]]; 

NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];    
[tempDictionary setObject:productName forKey:@"name"];        
[tempArray release];
```

I am getting a NSException crash with [this](http://www.mediafire.com/?i0j43x9kc767qgu) report. Please help.

Comment: You can actually copy and paste the crash log instead of making the screen shot.

Comment: I am not good in formatting ... surely I shall improve ..

Comment: Are you trying to make a gain out of advertisement cluttered links you post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method **getObjects:range:** that is being sent to your NSDictionary instance is a NSArray method.

You're probably trying to to your **initWithArray** passing a **NSDictionary** instead of a **NSArray**.

Answer (score -1):

Is the NSLog entry showing up? If not, it's because tempArray does not respond to retainCount. You don't need to worry about anything with `release` or `retain` if you're using Xcode 4.2 with ARC for iOS 5 (which you should, unless you have legacy code).

Otherwise, somewhere you're sending an object a message it doesn't respond to.

Comment: I am using XCode 4. The NSLog entry is showing up with retain count 0.

Comment: It only shows up because you are lucky; tempArray is nil.  retainCount is useless and irrelevant in this case.